# Update изменяет предыдущую запись

Tags: c#, sql

Некоторое время назад мой запрос на обновление вполне работал,сейчас же происходит не понятное.Мне нужно было написать запрос на обновление двух полей.Если я выберу значение в комбобокс изменю название, текст рецепта и нажму кнопку то данные должны обновится

*Да я знаю что запрос и таблица кривая,целиком перепахать программу времени нет.*

Я изменил название кулич бездрожжевой на кулич бездрожжевой123 и вот что получилось

Как было

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как стало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
if (teb2.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    if (vivodnamerecept.Text.Equals("") && vivodtextrecept.Text.Equals(""))
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = 
            MessageBox.Show("Нужно ввести название рецепта, текст рецепта ");
    }
    else
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database777.mdb;";
        conn.Open();
        string my_querry2 = "update Десерт set [Название рецепта]='" 
            + vivodnamerecept.Text + "',[Текст рецепта]='" 
            + vivodtextrecept.Text + "'  ";
        OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry2, conn);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)Firstimage2.Source));

        using (var stream = File.Create(@"images//" + vivodnamerecept.Text + ".png"))
            encoder.Save(stream);

        vivodtext.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        vivodcartinki.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        refaac.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        teb2.Items.Clear();
        teb4.Items.Clear();
        teb6.Items.Clear();
        teb8.Items.Clear();
        teb10.Items.Clear();

        hoho();
    }
}
```

Comment: Первичный ключ имеется в таблице?

Comment: Название рецепта это ключевое поле @SultanovShamil

Comment: я не вижу условия, по которой выбирается запись из таблицы на обновление (добавьте WHERE) чтобы не затрагивать другие записи.
Во вторых, такое построение SQL запроса через конкатенацию строк чревато SQL инъекциями, нужно экранировать и параметризировать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем создал третье поле счетчик с типом счетчик и привязял его к текстбоксу.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = 
    new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database777.mdb;";
conn.Open();
string my_querry2 = "update Десерт set [Название рецепта]='" 
    + vivodnamerecept.Text + "',[Текст рецепта]='" 
    + vivodtextrecept.Text + "' where[Счетчик]=" + id.Text + "  ";
OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry2, conn);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```